# Proof that real quadratic forms are always diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, diagonalization, quadratic-forms

I'm having some trouble understanding Theorem 1 in Chapter 8 of Lax's book on Linear Algebra.  This chapter is "spectral theory of self-adjoint mappings of a Euclidean space".  The theorem is that

> Given a real quadratic form $$q(y) = \sum_{i,j} h_{ij} y_i y_j$$
> it is possible to change variables as in $Ly=z$ s.t. in terms of the new variabls, $z, q$ is diagonal, i.e. of the form
> $$q \left( L^{-1} z \right) = \sum_{1}^{n}d_iz_i^2 \tag{11}\label{11}$$

---

The proof is as follows.

The proof is entirely elementary and constructive.  Suppose that one of the diagonal elements of $q$ is non-zero, say $h_{11}\ne0$.  We then group together all terms containing $y_1$
$$q(y)=h_{11}y_1^2+\sum_{2}^{n}h_{1j}y_1y_j+\sum_{2}^{n}h_{ij}y_iy_j$$
Since $H$ is symmetric, $h_{j1}=h_{1j}$, and so we can write
$$h_{11}\left(y_1+h_{11}^{-1}\sum_{2}^{n}h_{1j}y_j\right)^2-h_{11}^{-1}\left(\sum_{2}^{n}h_{1j}y_j\right)^2$$
Set
$$y_1+h_{11}^{-1}\sum_{2}^{n}h_{1j}y_j=z_1\tag{12}$$
We can then write
$$q(y)=h_{11}z_1^2+q_2(y)\tag{13}\label{13}$$
where $q_2$ depends only on $y_2,\dots,y_n$.

If all diagonal terms of $q$ are zero but there is some non-zero off-diagonal term, say $h_{12}=h_{21}\ne0$, then we introduce $y_1+y_2$ and $y_1-y_2$ as new variables, which produces a non-zero diagonal term.  If all diagonal and off-diagonal terms are zero, then $q(y)\equiv0$ and there is nothing to prove.

We now apply induction on the number of variables $n$.  Using (13) shows that if the quadratic function $q_2$ in $(n-1)$ variables can be written in form (11), then so can $q$ itself.  Since $y_2,\dots,y_n$ are related by an invertible matrix to $z_2,\dots,z_n$, it follows from (12) that the full set $y$ is related to $z$ by an invertible matrix.

This proof seems to skip the step of showing that the matrix is actually invertible.  As far as I can tell, this method gives an upper triangular matrix $L$.  However it doesn't seem to show or give a reason why $L$ is immediately invertible.  I think I'm able to follow the reasoning up to (and including) the induction, but it's the last few sentences about invertibility that I'm confused about.

Comment: The invertibility can be derived from the following: assume $L_{n-1}$ is an invertible $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix. Let $L_n $ be the $n\times n$ matrix obtained from $L_{n-1}$ by adding (the first) row with nonzero element on the position $(1,1)$ and arbitrary other elements, and completing the first column with $0$ entries. Then $L_n$ is invertible.

Comment: Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple.  Since $y_i$ and $z_i$ are "coordinates", they can be treated as constant.  Since $q_2$ does not include any terms with $y_1$, this mapping is injective and so the matrix representing this mapping is invertible.